# nodejs and less - pick stylesheet source based on subdomain

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, less

I'm using nodejs, express, jade, and less.

I route to a bunch of different subdomains (i.e. college1.domain.com, college2.domain.com).
Each college gets a customized stylesheet. How can I be selective about which stylesheet to load?

I don't want to pass around a variable and decide when rendering the page which to load.

I would rather separate the stylesheets into different subdirectories and then tell the less-middleware to look at a specific directory based on the subdomain. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your stylesheets are static files you could put nginx in front of your app server and let it serve the correct assets based on domain name and/or path (directly - not through your app). It might even be faster/better to let nginx do it since your app will have more resources to do app-stuff instead of serving assets.

Here's a sample configuration from the nginx documentation (slightly modified):

```
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }

  location /stylesheets/ {
    root /path/to/your/stylesheets;
  }
}
```

This sends all requests to your app except those starting with `/stylesheets/` which are fetched directly from the file system.

Check out the [beginner's guide to nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) for more info.